# How to count non-zero occurrences of a char in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am new in C programming. I would like to ask how I can store a char in a char array? The reason why I want to do it is because I get a char from a computation I make. This computation returns a char consisting of 4. I want to look through every character of the 4 and check if they are "0". If not, then I will increment by one. This is an example of a substitution: "0xf3"- I am trying to compute the Hamming Weight of a substitution. This is how I try to count how many non-zero the char consists of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char x = "0xf3";

    char s[10] = x;

    int lingh = strlen(s); 

    for (int i = 0; i<lingh;i++) {

        printf("%c\n", s[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output I expect is something like s[] = {0,x,f,3}

Comment: What is `char x = 0xf3;` here?

Comment: it's the hex value of 243

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "This computation returns a char consisting of 4." Is that a char with value 4, or is it 4 chars, or something else?

Comment: check this assignment carefully---------> `char s[10] = x;`

Comment: it consists of 4 chars..

Comment: How are you storing those characters in `char` type variable?

Comment: Where are these four characters? You're not composing a valid NUL-terminated C string here. You need to do that first.

Comment: `char x` declares x as single variable for a character value (a single letter, like `'a'` or `'b'`). `"0xf3"` is a string of characters, it's: `{ '0', 'x', 'f', '3' '\0' }`, 5 characters including the terminating null byte. `char s[10]` is a char array for 10 characters. `char  x = "0xf3"` and `char s[10] = x` is just invalid and comes from not understanding pointers. You can `char x[] = "0xf3"` and `char *s = x`. or `char s[10]; strcpy(s, x);`

Answer (score 0):

> **This computation returns a char consisting of 4**.

You are saying your computation returns a character which consists of 4 characters. Is it possible???

I guess your computation returns a string that consists of 4 characters. Example `0xf3`

You can not store a `string literal` in `char` type variable.

```
char x = "0xf3";  //<---------------------
```

You can store them in a character array like `char x[] = "0xf3";`

Here is the modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //<---- for strlen() and strcpy()

int main()
{

    char x[] = "0xf3";  //<----store in a char array

    char s[10];

    strcpy(s, x);  //<----copy in another array 

    int lingh = strlen(s); 

    for (int i = 0; i<lingh;i++) {

        printf("%c\n", s[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 0xf3 is hexadecimal value. I tried to save char x = '0xf3', but it gives me error. with short words: I have 0xf3 (it is hexadecimal) and I want to store it is in array s[], so that should be like s[] = {0,x,f,3}.

Comment: @user8231110 you have to store "oxf3" in a char array as I did. Now s[] is storing "oxf3".

Comment: I do understand that, but the problem is that the char I have to store in the array is computed in another function, namely by the substitution (S-Box from crypto)

Comment: @user8231110 then store the return value of that function in `char x[]`